# Testing a method that returns null at the end

Tags: java, maven, testing, jdbc, junit

```
public class CustomerDAO implements Dao<Customer> {

public static final Logger LOGGER = LogManager.getLogger();

    @Override
    public Customer modelFromResultSet(ResultSet resultSet) throws SQLException {
        Long id = resultSet.getLong("id");
        String firstName = resultSet.getString("firstName");
        String surname = resultSet.getString("surname");
        return new Customer(id, firstName, surname);
    }
    @Override
    public Customer create(Customer customer) {
        try (Connection connection = DBUtils.getInstance().getConnection();
                PreparedStatement statement = connection
                        .prepareStatement("INSERT INTO customers(firstName, surname) VALUES (?, ?)");) {
            statement.setString(1, customer.getFirstName());
            statement.setString(2, customer.getSurname());
            statement.executeUpdate();
            return readLatest();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            LOGGER.debug(e);
            LOGGER.error(e.getMessage());
        }
        return null;
    }
}
```

The create method above is the one I am trying to test.

```
public class CustomerDAOTest {

    private final CustomerDAO DAO = new CustomerDAO();

    @Test
    public void testCreate() {
        final Customer created = new Customer(2L, "chris", "perrins");
        assertEquals(created, DAO.create(created));
    }
}
```

This is the test I wrote, but obviously the create method will return null, and the created variable won't, therefore the test fails. What can I do to work around this? The original method is not my own code, it's a learning exercise, so ideally I wouldn't want to change it that much if that's a possibility.

Comment: Normally, to test code like this, you'd test two methods at once - a method that creates the data and a method that selects it back from the database.  Your test would call the create method, then call the select method, and check that the object that was selected matches the object that was created.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well you could use assertNull:

`assertNull(Dao.create(created));`